# How are DataGridView columns named when populated by a Typed DataSet?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

When a DataGridView is populated via a typed DataSet how/what does it naturally name the columns?

Ex:

```
Dim sqlstrg as String = "SELECT [Welding_CWB].[CWB_Process] AS 'Process', [Welding_CWB].[CWB_Classification] AS 'Class', [Welding_CWB].[CWB_Position] AS 'Position', [Welding_CWB].[CWB_Standard] AS 'Standard', [Welding_CWB].[CWB_Thickness_Range] AS 'Thickness', [Welding_CWB].[CWB_Expiry] AS 'Expiry' FROM [Welding_CWB];"
Dim cs as String = My.Settings.ConnectionString
Dim con as new SqlConnection(cs)
Dim ds as new DataSet
Dim da as new DqlDataAdapter(sqlstrg, con)

con.open()
da.fill(ds, "TableName")
con.close()

Datagridview1.Datasource = ds.Tables(0)
```

What I am referring to is:

```
For I As Integer To Me.datagridview1.rows.count - 1

Me.Datagridview1.Rows(I).cells(Name of column).value 
                                     ^
Next                                 |
                                     |
```

What would the Name of the Column be?  Is there a way one can specify what that name is?

Comment: what do you mean exactly "how/what does it naturally name the columns?"

Comment: Ambitiouz, I added more to the original question so the formatting is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless otherwise defined by the `ColumnName` property, columns will be named the same as the source `DataTable`.

```
' Wrap the source DataTable in a DataView.
Datagridview1.Datasource = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))

For I As Integer To Me.datagridview1.rows.count - 1
    Me.Datagridview1.Rows(I).cells("NameFromSourceSQL").value
Next
```

In your case, valid names would be:

- Process
- Class
- Position
- Standard
- Thickness
- Expiry

You can iterate the columns names by doing something like this:

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    MessageBox.Show("Column Name = " & col.ColumnName & " / Header = " & col.HeaderText)
Next
```